# How to efficiently retry after failing Mongoid uniqueness validation?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a Mongoid model which requires two fields to be unique. I want to generate the "unique number" value and retry if it becomes not unique in the time it took to save.

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :number
  field :name

  index({ number: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })
  index({ name: 1   }, { unique: true, background: true })

  validates_presence_of   :number, :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :number, :name

  def self.make!(name)
    find_or_initialize_by(name: name).tap do |model|
      if model.new_record?
        model.number = generate_random_number
        model.save! # fails validation because number is no longer unique
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I retry when the uniqueness collision happens?

Answer (score 0):

Begin
Rescue
Retry

Check
[this example](http://blog.mirthlab.com/2012/05/25/cleanly-retrying-blocks-of-code-after-an-exception-in-ruby/)